QGIS: Merge multiple layers in modeler - mixed Polygon and PolygonZ
We are building a QGIS model that contains multiple layer inputs for polygon layers to be merged in a next step. However, some of the layers are of type PolygonZ, others of type Polygon. This leads to an error when running the model. When using a single vector layer input, the "Drop M/Z values" tool helps. But this can't take multiple layers as input.
Is there a way to handle multiple layer inputs with mixed Polygon types, so that we don't have to drop M/Z for each relevant single layer beforehand?

Merge Vector Layer accepts a multiple input parameter so you can start with a merge, then drop M/Z on the merge output. If you then need to split the output into separate layers again you can extract by expression by the layer or path attributes created in the Merge.
